# Why there is no conversion when casting nullable type to it's base class in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Lets take the following code:

```
int? a = null;
int b = (int)a;
```

And extract `CastExpressionSyntax` for `(int)a` expression.

There is no conversion:

```
semanticModel.GetConversion(node) == {Identity}
```

There is no symbol (I hoped for `Nullable<T>` `implicit operator T`)

```
semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Method == null
```

Type info's both values are same

```
semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node) == {Type = Int32, ConvertedType = Int32}
semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node.Expression) == {Type = Int32?, ConvertedType = Int32?}
```

Is there a correct way to detect nullable to non nullable cast, or i need to manually look if one of type infos is nullable and other is not?

Example of a different behavior:

Lets take structure:

```
 public struct N<T> where T : struct
 {
     public static explicit operator T(N<T> value)
     {
        return default(T);
     }
 }
```

And use it like nullable before

```
 N<int> e;
 int d = (int) e;
```

@Kirk Woll is right that `GetConversion` and `GetTypeInfo` would be the same, but `GetSymbolInfo` would return `public static explicit operator T(N<T> value)` method.

Nullable has exactly the same method, but it's not returned.

There is no call to operator emmited compiller generates direct call to Value property.

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // a
IL_0003:  initobj     System.Nullable<System.Int32>
IL_0009:  ldloca.s    00 // a
IL_000B:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_Value
IL_0010:  stloc.1     // b
```

Comment: Doesn't the type info for `node` vs `node.Expression` give you the answer?

Comment: @KirkWoll, It does, kind of, but usually conversion is there, so I wondered whats so special about this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a cast operation:

```
int b = (int)a;
```

You have the cast expression:

```
(int)a
```

The `CastExpressionSyntax` has an `Expression` property (representing `a`) and the `Type` property (representing `int`).  Thus in my implementation of this using `VisitCastExpression`, I query both values to determine the from and the to of the cast:

```
var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(node.Expression);
var originalType = typeInfo.Type;
var convertedType = typeInfo.ConvertedType;
var destinationType = model.GetTypeInfo(node.Type).Type;
```

`destinationType` is always what you are casting to (in your case `int`).  `originalType` is the type of the expression before it has undergone any implicit conversions.  And `convertedType` is the type of the expression after it has undergone any implicit conversions.  In your example, the `convertedType` and the `originalType` should both be `int?`.

So I'm not entirely sure in what way you were hoping Roslyn would behave differently, but it seems to me to be behaving exactly as I'd expect.

As far as why the symbol information is not being returned, my guess is that the compiler doesn't actually emit code that invokes that operator overload and handles such conversions implicitly. Thus it would have been incorrect if it provided that symbol.

Comment: You are right please add you comment to answer itself